# RabbitVcs and Ubuntu 14

Tags: rabbitvcs

I've installed RabbitVcs on Ubuntu 14:
    `sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3 rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-core rabbitvcs-cli`

Now I'm trying to clone repository from github, but RabbitVcs just shows a blank window with title: 'Notification messages' and that's all. I can drop this window but when I try to commit changes I can see that frozen empty window again. Why does it happen? Is this a bug in the app or I've made some mistakes during installation RabbitVcs?

---

Ok, I've tested RabbitVcs on other distros and it works fine there. So this is unity's bug.

Comment: Did you look at the versions of RabbitVcs you tried? sometimes the version in the ubuntu repos is a bit old. If you really think it is a bug though, please [report it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).